# Getting wrong input error in pytorch model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, semantic-segmentation

I am getting the following error when I am trying to execute a model in pytorch.

`Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 4, 4], expected input[1, 4, 512, 512] to have 3 channels, but got 4 channels instead`

I understand that the input image I am giving to the model has 4 channels and it requires to have 3 instead. But, can someone tell me what is the meaning of each number in the parenthesis and from where can I start to debug this problem? Because I am giving 2 types of images and labels for the images as input to the model.

If you require any more information, please comment. I will happy to provide.

Comment: input[1, 4, 512, 512] means `[batch_size, channels, height, width]` .To debug this problem, you can start by looking at the code that loads the image data and make sure that it is loading images with the correct number of channels. If your image has 4 channel then you can remove 1 channel from image by `PIL` or `OpenCV` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel group is of size [`64,3,4,4`] -

- 64 filters or kernels in this layer
- 3 channels per kernel (should match channels per image)
- kernel size (height and width) of 4 and 4, respectively

And in your image, as state in comments - `[1,4,512,512]` = [batch size, channels, height, width].

To address this issue, you can either remove a channel from your image, or else add an additional channel to dimension 1 of the kernel, something like this:

```
model.conv1.shape #  [64,3,4,4]

new_conv_layer = torch.nn.Conv2d(4, 64, kernel_size=4)

# initialize first 3 channels with values from old layer
new_conv_layer.weight.data[:,:3,:,:] = model.conv1.weight.data.clone()

# initialize new channel however you want
new_conv_layer.weight.data[:,3,:,:] =  ... 

# assign replacement layer 
model.conv1 = new_conv_layer

model.conv1.shape  # [64,4,4,4]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have chosen the approach of removing one channel from my image tensor. After doing that the codes works file. Thank you for suggestion.